# auto resize jTable as incresing numer of rows in netbeans java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a billing system in java i have almost completed this but i have one problem to resize Jtable with increasing number of rows in netbeans.
Jtable is getting data from another table from sales chember and making bill here 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFjR7.png)

here is what , my problem i have added two quantities and displaying only 1 Jtable is not automatically increasing as increasing number of rows
here is my code

```
     /** To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates* and open the template in the editor.*/
    package project;

    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.print.*;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.*;

    /**
     *
    * @author Xeeshan Khan
    */
    public class reciept extends javax.swing.JPanel implements Printable{
    static DateFormat date=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");

    JFrame f=new JFrame();

    static SimpleDateFormat time=new SimpleDateFormat("h:m:s a");

    static Date d=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());  
    Connection conn;

    /**
     * Creates new form reciept
     */
    public reciept() {
      initComponents();
      conn=DB.con();       
      cal();
      jTable1.setBackground(Color.white);
    }

     @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int i) throws PrinterException {
        if (i > 0) {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
        reciept.this.printAll(g);
        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public void cal() {            
        reciept.jTable1.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Dialog",Font.PLAIN,7));
        jTable1.setBackground(Color.decode("#FFFFFF"));

        String s=date.format(d);
        String ta=time.format(d);

        t.setText(ta);

        da.setText(s);
        jLabel12.setText(sale.ca);
        String cas=String.valueOf(sale.bill);
        jLabel14.setText(cas);

        tb.setText(sale.b);

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

         double sum=0;

         for(int i=0; i<jTable1.getRowCount(); i++)
         {

             String d=jTable1.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
             double d1=Double.parseDouble(d);
             sum+=d1;
         }

         String q1=String.valueOf(sum);

         tq.setText(q1);    

         //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    try {
        Statement st=conn.createStatement();

        String sql="SELECT billnumber From bill";
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rs.next())
        {            
            int bill=rs.getInt("billnumber");

            String bnum=String.valueOf(bill);
            bn.setText(bnum);
            bill++;
            st.executeUpdate("UPDATE bill Set billnumber='"+bill+"'");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(reciept.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        bn = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        da = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        t = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tq = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tb = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jSeparator6 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel16 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        Object[] col={ "S#","Dis","Price","Qty","Disc","Amt"};

        DefaultTableModel tm=new DefaultTableModel(sale.tabledata,col);
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/project/logo.png"))); // NOI18N
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(56, 0, 74, 45));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trajan Pro", 1, 21)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Tayyab Fabrics");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(22, 51, -1, -1));

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Shop No. G-1, Rabi Center , Hariyanwala Chowk, D-Ground");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 79, 400, -1));

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Ph #  041-8546800");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(73, 108, 105, -1));

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Aharoni", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Sales Receipt");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(64, 146, -1, 21));

        jSeparator1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jPanel1.add(jSeparator1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 124, 223, -1));

        bn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Agency FB", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        bn.setText("Number # !");
        jPanel1.add(bn, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 149, 36, 14));

        da.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Agency FB", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        da.setText("Date");
        jPanel1.add(da, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(79, 129, 83, 16));

        t.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Agency FB", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        t.setText("Time");
        jPanel1.add(t, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(147, 146, 85, 21));

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setText("Total Qty");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 380, -1, -1));

        tq.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        tq.setText("jLabel10");
        jPanel1.add(tq, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(51, 380, 40, 10));

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setText("Total");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel10, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(104, 381, 31, -1));

        tb.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        tb.setText("jLabel11");
        jPanel1.add(tb, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(151, 383, 50, 7));

        jSeparator2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jPanel1.add(jSeparator2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 397, 224, -1));

        jLabel14.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel14.setText("jLabel14");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel14, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(152, 405, 70, 17));

        jLabel13.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel13.setText("Cash return");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel13, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(101, 405, -1, 16));

        jLabel12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel12.setText("jLabel12");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel12, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(55, 405, 40, 16));

        jLabel11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel11.setText("Cash Recieved");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel11, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 410, -1, -1));

        jSeparator6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jPanel1.add(jSeparator6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 479, 237, -1));

        jLabel15.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel15.setText("Sold product can be exchanged within 8 days");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel15, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 428, 209, 14));

        jLabel16.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel16.setText("Thank you for Shoping here");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel16, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(37, 448, 160, -1));

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Software Contact:");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(22, 464, 65, 9));

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("+92 306 909 6975");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(97, 464, 90, 9));

        jTable1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 6));
        jTable1.setModel(tm);
        jTable1.setEnabled(false);
        jTable1.setFocusable(false);
        jTable1.setRowHeight(14);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jPanel1.add(jScrollPane1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 173, 192, 40));

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setText("Faisalalabad");
        jPanel1.add(jLabel8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(84, 92, 58, -1));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 487, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel bn;
    private javax.swing.JLabel da;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel14;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel15;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel16;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator2;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator6;
    public static javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel t;
    private javax.swing.JLabel tb;
    private javax.swing.JLabel tq;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                final reciept pt = new reciept();
                f.add(pt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
              JButton b = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Print") {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                         PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                         Paper paper = new Paper();
                         PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
                         pf.setPaper(paper);
        pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
                         pj.setPrintable(pt, pf);

                            try {
                                pj.print();
                            } catch (PrinterException pe) {
                                pe.printStackTrace(System.err);
                            }

                      }
                });

                f.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(b);
                b.requestFocus();
                JPanel p = new JPanel();
                p.add(b);
                p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                f.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                f.pack();

                f.setVisible(true);                    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any idea to solve this problem

Comment: just increase size of JTable in design panel of NetBeans. `JTable` is added in `JScrollPane` when you code using netbeans drag drop facility.

Comment: If number of rows increased, `JScrollPane` will add scroll bars.

Comment: infact i have the same problem. i dont want to add my table in scroll bar because im printing the bill if i add rows by draging Jtable to my frame and add rows more than the height of JTable then it makes scroll bar and further added rows dont print.